# 403 forbidden error occured

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, timthumb

I have hosted a new website on shared server(so no apache error log access). All is working fine, except images coming from timthumb. Error might be in .htaccess file and it working properly on my local environment. I have PHP version 5.3 on local while server has 5.4
below is the code of my .htaccess file

```
# deny *everything*
<FilesMatch ".*">
   #Order Allow,Deny
   #Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# but now allow just *certain* necessary files:
<FilesMatch ".*\.(js|JS|css|CSS|jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|swf|SWF|php)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
 </FilesMatch>

 IndexIgnore */*

 OPTIONS -Indexes -ExecCGI
```

[this](http://shop.ghanasoccernet.com/includes/templates/new_ukss_design/images/timthumb.php?src=new_home_page/ac-milan-badge.jpg&h=75) is the  link of the image with timthumb while [this](http://shop.ghanasoccernet.com/includes/templates/new_ukss_design/images/new_home_page/arsenal-badge.jpg) is the link of the image without timthumb. Please help.

Comment: What CHMOD permissions are set on the TimThumb script? It needs execute and write permissions on the cache directory, so chmod timbthumb.php to 644 and cache dir to 755 or 777 if that fails.

Comment: @i-CONICA chmod permissions are 0644 and error must relate to .htaccess because I just renamed .htaccess and found that images starts appearing

Comment: Oh, I don't think your filesmatch pattern is matching the files properly. Try <FilesMatch "\.(js|JS|css|CSS|jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|swf|SWF|php)$">

Comment: Might want to comment out IndexIgnore */* too.

Comment: sorry, but both didn't work for me

Comment: You need to help too. Troubleshoot? If the htaccess file is causing the problem, delete everything from it and see if it works, if so, then slowly add the contents back, section by section until it breaks and you've narrowed down the problem by a process of elimination. You can then ask a question about why the particular bit of code doesn't work.

Comment: @i-CONICA thatnks for suggestion. I have tried it and found if I remove "OPTIONS -Indexes -ExecCGI", it works fine for me. Will you please tell me is it mandatory to include and what is its need?

Comment: Hi, it's not needed. The -Indexes means that it won't show directory indexes, but it's likely configured that way anyway by default with your hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Your timthumb link ends in the number 75, and not one of the extensions you have in FilesMatch. Try removing the $ if you want the extension to match anywhere in the url.

Comment: Thanks Johnh for your suggestion, but its not working. However, issue has been resolved now. I ave removed "OPTIONS -Indexes -ExecCGI" and its working now :)